# Is there a way to pair dictionary items?

Tags: python, dictionary

What I want to do is be able to go through my dictionary and print out two values at a time in pairs, without ever doubling up on them.
So if I had:

```
dict = {'player1':'Bob' , 'player2':'John', 'player3':'Greg', 'player4':'Tim'}
```

I want it to be able to divide it into pairs of two without doubling up.
So I could get

> Bob and John, Greg and Tim OR Bob and Greg, John and Tim.

Sorry if I didnt explain this very well, but hopefully you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = {'player1':'Bob' , 'player2':'John', 'player3':'Greg', 'player4':'Tim'}

players = list(d.values())
print(', '.join('{} and {}'.format(players[i], players[i+1]) for i in range(0, len(players), 2)))
```

prints (for example):

```
John and Greg, Bob and Tim
```

You can replace the second line with

```
players = sorted(d.values())
```

to get an alphabetically sorted list of players. Otherwise the order will be arbitrary.

Works for an even number of players only.

Comment: @user2098639 - try to call `print` as a function (see my edited answer).

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import random
>>> D = {'player1':'Bob' , 'player2':'John', 'player3':'Greg', 'player4':'Tim'}
>>> players = D.values()
>>> random.shuffle(players)   # I'm guessing you don't want fixed pairs
>>> for i in zip(*[iter(players)]*2):
...  print i
... 
('Bob', 'Tim')
('Greg', 'John')
```